# Data is empty when update to database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had a problem when I try Django, I had a function like this:

```
def function(id):
   data = { a: "a", b:"b", c:"c" }
   model = Models.objects.get(id=id)
   print(json.dumps(data)) # when try to print this, there is a value 
   model.data = json.dumps(data) 
   # but when i tried to update my table in db, sometimes there is value, and sometimes is empty
   model.save()
```

Is anyone had any issues like this before?

Comment: I have not. You're logic seems sound with the example above. There must be something that is clearing that field in-between your **print** and **save** or between when you POST and before you check in your real code (IMO)

Comment: Please show your `models.py`. In particular your `class Models`, what is the `Models.data` you have there?

Comment: One thing that you can try is to perform your query in a single statement by doing something like this: `Models.objects.filter(id=id).update(data=data)`